# Create nested array in PHP from array by foreign keys

Tags: php, recursion

I am doing MySQL query to get a listing files/directories. Each one has an id, and optionally and "parent_id" that relates each file or directory to it's containing directory. It's a flat array off files and directories though. How can I, using php, build this into a nested array something like this where each "Files" can have multiple child "Files" recursively:

```
[{"Files":{"id": "1","name":"Parent", "parent_id":"null" "Files":{"id": "2","name":"Child", "parent_id":"1"}}, {"Files":{"id": "3","name":"Another top level dir", "parent_id":"null"}]
```

Thanks!

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718058/ordering-a-php-array/4718149#4718149

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a recursive function to assemble your nested array.  Here are some [links](http://devzone.zend.com/283/recursion-in-php-tapping-unharnessed-power/)  that [should help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648968/what-is-a-recursive-function-in-php) you to [get started](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/4/18/0).