# Optimizing multiple queries in MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, scalability

### Questions

1. How should I do the query(ies) to get this results?
2. Should I use a different structure for database tables?

### Details

I want to get results from 3 tables:

```
+------------------------------+-------------------+
| courses                      | id                | <-------+
|                              | name              |         |
|                              |                   |         |
+------------------------------+-------------------+         |
| sections                     | id                | <-------|----------+
|                              | course_id         | <- FK(courses.id)  |
|                              | name              |                    |
+------------------------------+-------------------|                    |
| resources                    | id                |                    |
|                              | section_id        | <- FK(sections.id)-+
|                              | name              |
+------------------------------+-------------------+
```

I want to store results in a PHP Array like this:

```
Array
(
    [courses] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => course 1
            [sections] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [course_id] => 1
                            [name] => course 1 section 1
                            [resources] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 1
                                            [section_id] => 1
                                            [name] => resource 1
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

---

**EDIT**

### What I did:

```
$cources = DB::query(Database::SELECT,
'select * from courses')->execute($db,false)[0];  // Get all courses as array

foreach($courses as &$course) {
    $sections = DB::query(Database::SELECT,
    'select * from sections where course_id = '.$courses['id']);

    $course['sections'] = $sections;

    foreach($course['sections'] as &&section) {
        $resources = DB::query(...); // Get array of resources
        $section['resources'] = $resources;
    }
}
```

Comment: **[What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)**

Comment: Optimize what queries? You didn't attach any. You can't get multi dimensional results from MySQL.

Comment: I updated the question with the PHP code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database structure is normalized - this is *correct* and should *not* be changed.

However, SQL returns de-normalized or "flattened" data for an N+ join: only a set of homogenous records can be returned in a single result-set. (Some databases, like SQL Server, allow returning structure by supporting XML generation.)

To get the desired array structure in PHP will require:

1. Separate queries/result-sets (as shown in the post): *ick!*

   There will about one query/object. While the theoretical bounds *might* be similar, the practical implementation will be *much less efficient* and the overhead will be much more than for single query. Remember that *every* query incurs (at the very least) a round-trip penalty - as such, this is **not scalable** although it will likely work just fine for smaller sets of data or for "time insensitive" operations.
2. Re-normalize the resulting structure:

   This is very trivial to do with support of a "Group By" operation, as found in C#/LINQ. I am not sure how this would be approached [easily] in PHP<sup>1</sup>. This isn't perfect either, but assuming that hashing is used for the grouping, this should be able to scale fairly well - it will definitely be better than #1.

Instead of the above, *consider writing the query in such a way that the "flat" result can be used within the current problem/scope*, if possible. That is, analyze how the array is to be *used* - then write the queries around that problem. This is often a better approach that can scale *very* well.

---

<sup>1</sup> Related to re-normalizing the data, YMMV:

- [SQL result to PHP multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123264/sql-result-to-php-multidimensional-array)
- [PHP array to multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813881/php-array-to-multidimensional-array?rq=1)
- [Group a multidimensional array by a particular value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189626/php-how-to-group-a-multidimensional-array-by-a-particular-value)

Comment: So, if I understood, I get results like: `(course_info), (section_info), (resource_info)` for each query row and "filter" the data with PHP. Thats it?

Comment: @GiovanneAfonso For #2, where "filter" means "re-normalize", then yes. If you need *every* record, see Travis G's answer, but if you *only* need some (i.e. using a WHERE) then a JOIN, as shown in MIIB's answer, is the way to go. Note that they return distinctly different results and so must be re-normalized differently.

Answer (score 1):

You cant get multi dimensional result from mysql. The query for getting the elements should be like this:

```
select courses.id as coursesId,courses.name as coursesName,sections.id as sectionsId,sections.name as sectionsName,resources.id as resourcesId, resources.name as resourcesName
from courses
left join sections on courses.id=sections.course_id
left join resources on sections.id=resources.section_id;
```

But ofcourse it will not give you the array as you like.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
SELECT * FROM (
select c.id, c.name from courses c
union
select s.id, r.name,s.course_ID from sections s
union
select r.id, r.name,r.section_ID from resources r
)
```

Comment: I have a lot of another different columns in each table (didn't put there to make it simple to read). So I would get a different "column count" for each table. Can I still use something like this?

Answer (score 0):

```
        if you are familiar with php then you can use this code i am writing only 2nd level you can write same way with third label
    $final=array();
           $c=-1;
           $cid=false;
           $cname=false;
           $query = "SELECT c.*,s.*,r.* FROM  courses AS c LEFT JOIN sections AS s ON c.id=s.course_id LEFT JOIN resources AS r ON r.section_id =s.id";
           $result=mysql_query($query, $this->con) or die(mysql_error());
           while($row=  mysql_fetch_array($result)){
               if($cid!=$row[2]){
                   $final['cources'][++$c]['id']=$cid=$row[0];
                   $final['cources'][$c]['name']=$cname=$row[1];
                   $s=-1;


               }
               $final['cources'][$c]['sections'][++$s]['id']=$row[2];
               $final['cources'][$c]['sections'][$s]['course_id']=$row[3];
              $final['cources'][$c]['sections'][$s]['name']=$row[4];
           }
           echo "<pre>";
           print_r($final);
           echo "</pre>";

//Outpur
Array
(
    [cources] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => c1
                    [sections] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 1
                                    [course_id] => 1
                                    [name] => s1-1
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 1
                                    [course_id] => 1
                                    [name] => s1-1
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [name] => c2
                    [sections] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 2
                                    [course_id] => 2
                                    [name] => s1-2
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```